# What is the most feasible way to authenticate using OAUTH2.0 in appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

code sample:

```
var propertyStore = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

//Logger.log(DriveApp.getFileById('1c4azrEgTFk7ujAF7dn2SL3whXEnTF6Mg'));

cGoa.GoaApp.setPackage(propertyStore,
    cGoa.GoaApp.createServiceAccount (DriveApp , {
    packageName: 'mypackage',
    fileId: '1c4azrEgTFk7ujAF7dn2SL3whXEnTF6Mg',
    scopes: cGoa.GoaApp.scopesGoogleExpand(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control']),
    service: 'google_service'
    }));
```

but without the comment line it shows error:

> You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive (line 256, file "GoaApp", project "cGoa")"

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the consent dialog cannot be opened for you (the script creator) to authorize it. To make it to, add a function with a call to DriveApp and run it. You should then be shown the consent screen to authorize. Then you can run the oneoff function.

```
function runThenDeleteMe() {
  DriveApp.getFiles();
}
```